# Row constructor comparison

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mariadb

In simple scenario:

```
SELECT (1,2) = (1,NULL)
-- NULL
```

When comparing:

```
SELECT ((1,2),1) = ((1,CAST(NULL AS INT)),1)
-- NULL        MariaDB/MySQL
-- False       PostgreSQL

SELECT ((1,2),CAST(NULL AS INT)) = ((1,CAST(NULL AS INT)),1)
-- NULL        MariaDB/MySQL
-- False       PostgreSQL
```

[db<>fiddle PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=754b51f31c3e42c63110b8c63d93193b)

[db<>fiddle MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=754b51f31c3e42c63110b8c63d93193b)

---

From PostgreSQL doc:

> [Row Constructor Comparison](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#ROW-WISE-COMPARISON)
>
> The = and <> cases work slightly differently from the others. Two rows are considered equal if all their corresponding members are non-null and equal; **the rows are unequal if any corresponding members are non-null and unequal; otherwise the result of the row comparison is unknown (null)**.

Does PostgreSQL treat "nested" record/row type differently? Which result is correct according to SQL Standard(MariaDB/PostgreSQL/both)?

Comment: Performance: Until very recently, MySQL/MariaDB did a very poor job with row constructors.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL and Postgre compare NULL values with `IS`, everything else is **undefined**

see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-comparison.html

ANd mysql does like the standard sql defines it

But as you can see in Mysql and mariadb there is to  compare  NULL [<=>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)

> ```
> SELECT (1,2) <=> (1,NULL)
> ```
>
> ```
> | (1,2) <=> (1,NULL) |
> | -----------------: |
> |                  0 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT ((1,2),1) <=> ((1,CAST(NULL AS INT)),1)
> ```
>
> ```
> | ((1,2),1) <=> ((1,CAST(NULL AS INT)),1) |
> | --------------------------------------: |
> |                                       0 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT ((1,2),1) <=> ((1,NULL),1)
> ```
>
> ```
> | ((1,2),1) <=> ((1,NULL),1) |
> | -------------------------: |
> |                          0 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT ((1,2),CAST(NULL AS INT)) <=> ((1,CAST(NULL AS INT)),1)
> ```
>
> ```
> | ((1,2),CAST(NULL AS INT)) <=> ((1,CAST(NULL AS INT)),1) |
> | ------------------------------------------------------: |
> |                                                       0 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT ((1,2),null) <=> ((1,null),1)
> ```
>
> ```
> | ((1,2),null) <=> ((1,null),1) |
> | ----------------------------: |
> |                             0 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=c87bc19125277b3063f719ca633bf386)*

For `SELECT ((1,2),CAST(NULL AS INT)) = ((1,CAST(NULL AS INT)),1)` i don't have an explanation, somehow if defines `CAST(NULL AS INT)`as 0  instead of NULL, but i couldn't find any kind of explanation, but as it is deterministic,,there should be a mention of it anywhere, but i couldn't find it.